# On super simple CPU: GCD of two inputs on super simple CPU

Tags: cpu, greatest-common-divisor

I was wondering how to find the GCD of two inputs on super simple CPU I have been struggling because there is only 16 bits of memory, so I am not sure how to edit the GCD program to accept two inputs without going beyond the memory capabilities? Could someone help please thank you!

Comment: With only 16 bits of memory (I assume you mean data memory rather than program memory) the inputs must be quite small, perhaps 4 bits each. Is that the case? How much program memory is there, and what are the available instructions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the euclidean gcd algorithm. If both inputs fit in 16 bits it will work for you
This is the pseudocode:

```
 function gcd(a, b)
      while b ≠ 0
          t := b; 
          b := a mod b; 
          a := t; 
  return a;
```